# sql-server in Kali Linux for Python

Tags: mysql, database

When I am trying to install MySQL-server in my Kali, I am again getting an error.

[image: MSQL Screenshot]

Then, I tried to install something else like `apt-get install MariaDB-server`. It was installed, but afterward when I tried to install I got this error:

[image]

Comment: You need to reset the password for root.